# How can i reproduce hs_err_pid*.log file?

Tags: java, jvm-crash

I am getting an error when going to restart HSQLDB.
I am getting Hot Spot Error log.
I want to reproduce that error in my local machine.
Can any one help me to reproduce hs_err_pid*.log file?
If so, what are the steps for that?

Comment: Repeat the same steps which produced the error on the server. There is no guarantee that you can repeat a crash bug on a different machine with different hardware and OS.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey-Thx a lot for prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter which JRE you use to compile the code below, if you run it under JRE1.7 you will get the error.

**The code:**

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class TestFileChooser{
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        try{
            //If you comment the code below, no error will occur
            DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:/DB_Test/DB_Test", 
            "userAdmin", "pass");
        }catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage());
        }   
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("C:");  
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);   
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

**The test (to reproduce the error):**

1. Compile and run the code below with JRE1.7
2. It will open a JFileChooser
3. Click the button to List Details of the files (at top right)
4. It will show a table of the files and its details
5. Click on the header of the table
6. The program will exit abruptly and a file hs_err_pid will be created